# Google Dialogflow - Beta version warning

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am in the process of creating a BOT using Google Dialogflow. Based on my need the free version "Standard Edition" would be sufficient.

I came across an [article][1] which mentions that it is in Beta

> This is a beta release of the Dialogflow V2 API. This product might be
>   changed in backward-incompatible ways and is not subject to any SLA or
>   deprecation policy. This product is not intended for real-time usage
>   in critical applications.

Though from the URL I could see that this restriction is applicable for Enterprise, I just wanted to make sure that Standard Edition do not have any such restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Both Dialogflow Standard and Enterprise Edition when using Dialogflow's v2 API are in beta.  In other words, both editions of Dialogflow's v2 API are in beta.
[image]
Dialogflow currently has two editions and two API versions.  When using Dialogflow's v1 API only Standard Edition is available and Dialogflow's v1 API Standard Edition is general available and *not in beta*.  When using Dialogflow's v2 API your agent can either be on the Standard or Enterprise Edition.  Dialogflow's v2 API is in beta regardless of whether you choose the Standard or Enterprise Edition.

Source: [Dialogflow's v2 API and Enterprise Edition launched recently and are currently in beta](https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/dialogflow-api-v2-and-enterprise-edition/).